# How to bundle a font in Angular Project so that it should not be downloaded from the internet?

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular9

I am using a font called as "Font Awesome" and I have an issue where I am expected to make the font available locally and not supposed to download the font from the internet, so that even if the client uses the the product offline right after installing then the client will be able to see the text in Font Awesome font.

[image: as we can see the font is downloaded using CDN]

**P.S.** I am using Angular 9 for FrontEnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

1. download it from npm/bower
2. Put it in fonts folder somewhere (I personally don't prefer assets cause angular mess with it),
3. Import it from .scss

styles.scss:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src: url('<dist folder path>/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
src: url('<dist folder path>/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),     
    url('<dist folder path>/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('<dist folder path>/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('<dist folder path>/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Note that `<dist folder path>` referes to the location where you download you assets from.
This is refering to the first cloud img in your img just above the CoreAMS folder

Most likely `<dist folder path>` = `fonts/`
if this folder is under the baseUrl in your tsconfig.json

Comment: Hi, i quite unable to find a proper way to download the Font Awesome font, I could only grab the regular font, can you help me with the BOLD and ITALIC ?

Comment: that `bower install components-font-awesome --save` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

In your case fontawesome provides a angular component.
[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome)